# Why using Count with IQueryable is considered unfeasible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, iqueryable

If I have the following code:-

```
IQueryable<People> list = repository.FindAllPeople;  
int count = list.Count();
```

Then is it considered as unfeasible to count IQueryable objects and it is better to use IEnumerable?
BR

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have been misinformed.

`IEnumerable` will use Linq to objects, all methods are executed on objects *in memory*. - `IQueryable` will use whatever implementation of the Linq extension methods is provided by the specific provider. In this case (a repository) I would guess it is most likely a provider that maps the Linq expressions to database statements.

That means if you use `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<People> list = repository.FindAllPeople;  
int count = list.Count();
```

The count is determined on the database itself, i.e. as a query `"select count(*) from People"`. This is usually very, very fast.

If you use `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<People> list = repository.FindAllPeople;  
int count = list.Count();
```

All People instances will be materialized to memory one by one while Linq to objects is iterating through the collection to determine the count. This will be very slow and should be avoided whenever possible.

Since not all method calls can be mapped to database queries it is sometimes unavoidable to use an `IEnumerable`, but all filtering, joining and grouping should be done on an IQueryable if possible, then as a last step you can use the `AsEnumerable()` extension methods to switch to using `IEnumerable` and Linq to objects.

Comment: Not in my case, running count on an excel document is not very good for performance. 300-400ms for about 350 rows. Thanks for your explanation though. Helped me understand why it's so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the infeasability of IQueryable, but [this blog post](http://sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12614) seems to indicate that IQueryable is much more preferable to IEnumerable because IQueryable allows access to the underlying expression.

This may only be relevant in the case of a Where clause and not impact .Count().