# Calling the Model method will work (with or without) using the .Tolist()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i have the following model method inside my asp.net MVc web application:-

```
public IQueryable<User> searchusers(string q, int id) 
        { 
            return from u in entities1.Users 
                 where (!u.Users_Classes.Any(c => c.ClassID == id) && (u.UserID.Contains(q)) 
                   select u; 
}
```

which will be called using the following action method:-

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
                 public PartialViewResult Search(string q, int classid)
                {

                    var users = r.searchusers(q, classid).ToList();

                    ViewBag.id = classid;
// code does here
               }
```

now if i remove the .ToList() from my action method the code will still work fine,, so will using the .ToList() method bring any advantages or features ?
BR

**Edit:-**
here is the full code for my action method:-

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
             public PartialViewResult Search(string q, int classid)
            {

                var users = r.searchusers(q, classid).ToList();
                                ViewBag.id = classid;
                return PartialView("_usersearch", users);

           }
```

Comment: Go though some articles on LINQ. This question and [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245933/why-using-count-with-iqueryable-is-considered-infeasible) are about the features of LINQ. If you have a specific question on usage LINQ do ask questions.

Comment: The users variable created is not used in your code or is some code removed?

Comment: see my update for the code. i just provided sample of the necessary code for my question.BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call ToList, you ask the Entity Framework to execute the query immediately, and then you will work with in memory collection. Otherwise, the query will be executed when you loop through the result.

Comment: i am not looping through the result at the controller, instead i am sending the "var users" to the view , so does this mean that the query will be executed when i loop though the model object at the view level!!.see my edit for the full code.BR

Comment: Yes, that is correct. With LINQ, you stack the queries, and all are executed when you actually need the results. This happens when you loop through the results, or when you retrieve the entire collection with methods like `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc.

Comment: John, you are right. Normally, I also do a ToList in my controller function,so I can easily determine what is returned. It's a bit hard to see what's going on in view page. But the big advantage if of deferred execution  is you only execute it when you need it.